# MySQL multiple joins with multiple counts in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query and it works as expected

```
SELECT i0_.address AS address0, COUNT(d1_.id) AS sclr2 
FROM IP i0_ 
LEFT JOIN Date_IP d3_ ON i0_.id = d3_.ip 
LEFT JOIN Date d1_ ON d1_.id = d3_.date 
GROUP BY i0_.address 
ORDER BY sclr2 DESC
```

This query also works as expected:

```
SELECT i0_.address AS address0, COUNT(u2_.id) AS sclr3 
FROM IP i0_ 
LEFT JOIN IP_UserAgent i4_ ON i0_.id = i4_.ip 
LEFT JOIN UserAgent u2_ ON u2_.id = i4_.useragent 
GROUP BY i0_.address 
ORDER BY sclr3 DESC
```

But How can I combine these two into one?

I tried

```
SELECT i0_.address AS address0, COUNT(d1_.id) AS sclr2, COUNT(u2_.id) AS sclr3 
FROM IP i0_ 

LEFT JOIN Date_IP d3_ ON i0_.id = d3_.ip 
LEFT JOIN Date d1_ ON d1_.id = d3_.date 

LEFT JOIN IP_UserAgent i4_ ON i0_.id = i4_.ip 
LEFT JOIN UserAgent u2_ ON u2_.id = i4_.useragent 

GROUP BY i0_.address 
ORDER BY sclr2 DESC
```

In this case value sclr2 is right but  sclr3 is the same as sclr2. What Am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine these by making them subqueries:

```
SELECT t1.address0, t1.sclr2, t2.sclr3
FROM (SELECT i0_.address AS address0, COUNT(d1_.id) AS sclr2 
      FROM IP i0_ LEFT JOIN 
           Date_IP d3_ ON i0_.id = d3_.ip LEFT JOIN
           Date d1_
           ON d1_.id = d3_.date 
      GROUP BY i0_.address
     ) t1 JOIN
     (SELECT i0_.address AS address0, COUNT(u2_.id) AS sclr3 
      FROM IP i0_ LEFT JOIN
           IP_UserAgent i4_
           ON i0_.id = i4_.ip LEFT JOIN
           UserAgent u2_
           ON u2_.id = i4_.useragent 
      GROUP BY i0_.address
     ) t2
     on t1.address0 = t2.address0;
```

As mentioned in another answer, `count(distinct)` can also work.  However, it produces an intermediate table which is the cartesian product of the "dates" and the "user agents".  So, if there are 100 dates and 100 user agents, the intermediate table would have 10,000 rows -- and if your data has many examples of this, then the processing time and intermediate storage requirements can become prohibitive.

Comment: +1 : Aggregate then Join.  Something surprisingly few people cotton on to in interviews.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
COUNT(DISTINCT d1_.id) AS sclr2, COUNT(DISTINCT u2_.id)
```

Comment: @kolacek - Please note, as per GordonLinoff's answer, this indeed does work; by removing duplication caused by the structure of your query, but at a potentially very large cost.  Depending on your data; aggregating in sub-queries, then joining the results, can be immensely quicker by avoiding the redundant duplication all together.  In essence this answer spends resources to cope with a mistake in the SQL, the other answer corrects the mistake in the SQL.

Comment: @MatBailie I actually agree with you. This was a quick solution, but I think it's less nice this way. I doubt about your remarks about performance, though. In Oracle this is probably the case, but MySQL has surprised me many times about how quick it can do aggregations like this, and how badly it performs when adding even the simplest of subqueries. That's why, for MySQL, I would at least compare the performance of my solution with the other one before rejecting it.

Comment: @GolezTrol - The issue mainly comes from the geometric growth of the data in the current joins.  If `d1` has 10 records in a "group" and `u2` has 10 records in that "group", they cross join and yield 100 records to process, compared to `10 + 10 = 20`  5 times as many records, but likely mostly in memory.  If the group sizes were 100 and 100 though, things get strikingly painful; 10k rows to process rather than 200.  And 100 isn't exactly a "small" number.  I've seen people do this kind of Cartesian Product on groups of thousands or more.

Comment: @MatBailie The 10k rows to be processed, that is true, but that kind of processing (counting) is very lightweight, especially when you're counting ids, which are probably indexed. Those 200 rows sounds less, but when they are built up using more complex selects, it may result in no or less efficient use of indices.